# Two database-tables for one model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-modeling

I am working with an existing sqlserver-database. 
In this database there are two tables containing "address-information".
One table has the information in French, the other in Dutch.
Both tables have the same layout.

```
[Key]
[Column("fu_VAT")]
public int VatNumber { get; set; }
[Column("fu_EindDatum")]
public int EindDatum { get; set; }
[Column("fu_vorm")]
public string Vorm { get; set; }
[Column("fu_NameOrigin")]
public int NameOrigin { get; set; }
[Column("fu_AdresOrigin")]
public int AdresOrigin { get; set; }
[Column("fu_Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Column("fu_StraatNaam")]
public string StraatNaam { get; set; }
```

So I have created a class "Addresse" which contains the above definition.
And then I created 2 classes "Addresse_FR" and "Addresse_NL" which inherit "Addresse".

In my repository I created the following method :

```
public Addresse GetCompanyAddressByLanguageAndVatNumber(int VatNumber, int Language)
{
    switch (Language)
    {
        case 1: //Frans
            return xmlALaCarteContext.CWFirmaAddresseFr.Where(a => a.VatNumber == VatNumber).SingleOrDefault().ToAddresse();
        default:
            return xmlALaCarteContext.CWFirmaAddresseNl.Where(a => a.VatNumber == VatNumber).SingleOrDefault().ToAddresse();
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a better way of solving this.

Comment: If both tables structure is exactly the same i wonder why not use same table for them both with with additional field which determine the culture/language.

Comment: @HagayGoshen As I said, it is an existing database. Other applications use the same database. I am not allowed to make changes to the database.

Comment: If you want a "cleaner" code solution you need to cleanup your db side.
if you cant change your db structure , you might be able to add a stored procedure that receive the culture/language id and returns data from the correct table , but then you moved your if condition from your app to your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you don't create "Magic numbers", i.e 1 = French, etc.  Why not use CultureInfo.Name?  Of course you probably could stick to first two characters for language regardless of location.  I found 6 for French alone.  The values are ISO standards.

```
// Language contains CultureInfo.Name (iso name that aligns to country/language)
public Addresse GetCompanyAddressByLanguageAndVatNumber(int VatNumber, string Language)
{
    switch (Language)
    {
        case "fr-CA": //Canadian French
        case "fr-FR": //France French
            return xmlALaCarteContext.CWFirmaAddresseFr.Where(a => a.VatNumber == VatNumber).SingleOrDefault().ToAddresse();
        case "nl-NL": //Netherlands Dutch
            return xmlALaCarteContext.CWFirmaAddresseFr.Where(a => a.VatNumber == VatNumber).SingleOrDefault().ToAddresse();
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You could also get tricky (love being bad) and have a Property Getter/Setter that uses virtual navigation properties to return the "right" address given the current culture and primary key (VAT is an FK I presume?)

```
public class myParent 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // navigation properties
    public int VatNumber { get; set; }
    private virtual Addresse FrenchAddress { get; set; }
    private virtual Addresse DutchAddress { get; set; }

    public Addresse CompanyAddress {
        get {
             switch (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.Name)
             {
                 case "fr-CA": //Canadian French
                 case "fr-FR": //France French
                     return FrenchAddress;
                 case "nl-NL": //Netherlands Dutch
                     return DutchAddress;
                 default:
                     throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

with corresponding Setter & fluent description.  I am not certain, but I think referencing CompanyAddress will cause the corresponding address to load.